# How to read last message node in firebase for js app?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to read last message node as shown in image below.

[image: Firebase console image of message]

I am using below query to retrieve last message where suid and ids are known(as shown in img). but not working.

```
firebase.database().ref("Messages/"+suid).child(ids+"/chat").orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
```

How to retrieve last message from firebase realtime db and display it to my console? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your existing code looks fine, so let's store that query in a variable first:

```
const query = firebase.database().ref("Messages/"+suid).child(ids+"/chat").orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
```

Now you can read the message(s) this query matches with either `once()` or `get()`. I'll use `once()`, since it's much older and hence you're more likely to find examples of it elsewhere:

```
query.once("value").then((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((message) => {
    console.log(message.val().message.msg);
  });
})
```

Some things to note here:

- Since a query may have multiple results, the `snapshot` contains a list of those results. Even if there's only a single result (like here), the `snapshot` is a list of one result. To loop over these results, we use `snapshot.forEach()`.
- Your `msg` is nested under `message` in each child, so we use `message.val().message.msg` to get at its value.